regex for a default URL validation that also includes the use of wildcards for both subdomain and top level domain
Is it possible to modify this current php regex to allow '*example.*'?
$wildcardUrlPattern = '/^(https?:\/\/)?(\*[a-z0-9-]*\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]*)*(\.\*[a-z0-9-]*)?$/i';

// Test URLs
$urls = [
    'example.*',      // Domain with wildcard TLD
    '*example.com',   // Wildcard domain with fixed TLD
    '*.example.*',    // Wildcard subdomain with wildcard TLD
    '*.example.com',  // Wildcard subdomain with fixed TLD
    '*example.*',     // Wildcard domain with wildcard TLD
    'http://example.*', // Protocol with domain and wildcard TLD
    'http://*example.com' // Protocol with wildcard domain and fixed TLD
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if (preg_match($wildcardUrlPattern, $url)) {
        echo "$url: Valid URL with wildcard\n";
    } else {
        echo "$url: Invalid URL\n";
    }
}

Result:
example.*: Valid URL with wildcard
*example.com: Valid URL with wildcard
*.example.*: Valid URL with wildcard
*.example.com: Valid URL with wildcard
*example.*: Invalid URL (should also be valid)
http://example.*: Valid URL with wildcard
http://*example.com: Valid URL with wildcard


Can you add examples of invalid URLs? Because currently everything seems to be valid.

@KIKOSoftware it should function as a default URL validation that also includes the use of wildcards for both subdomain and top level domain. Examples are the result.

Adding invalid URL's will help in testing your code. For instance, this URL: https://test.com?testing=true, doesn't pass, nor this one: *.*. The first is a perfectly fine URL, whereas the latter conforms to your description. I cannot tell whether these URLs are invalid because you want them to be or because you just didn't consider them.

How about this?
/^(?=.+\..+)(?:https?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9-\.*]+$/i

Here’s an explanation:

^ — start of string
(?=.+\..+) — lookahead (?=   ) to ensure the string contains least one dot \. with a character .+ either side of it
(?:https?:\/\/)? — optional scheme (not captured)
[a-z0-9-\.*]+ — a sequence of uninterrupted alphanumeric characters, hyphens, dots or asterisks
$ — end of string

See it working on regex101, although note that for testing purposes I have included the /m flag so that ^ and $ match the start and end of each line (rather than the start and end of the string), and the /g flag so that it won’t stop after finding the first match. I included a second group of test cases which I imagine should not match.
